# How to replace a NULL value in SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have a table `dbo.People` in a database and one of the columns is `Name`. Some of the fields however are missing a Name value. So I am trying to replace the empty field with `No Name`. There is also an `ID` column with values `1, 2, 3, 4,` and so on.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT ISNULL(Name, 'No Name') FROM dbo.People;
```

I then want to group and count how many times that name occurs

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), Name
FROM dbo.People
GROUP BY Name;
```

This works, however my result still shows a blank value with how many times that blank value occurs, rather than `No Name`.

Comment: you didn't use the `ISNULL(Name, 'No Name' )` in your second query at all

Comment: Simply selecting on your first query doesn't change the underlying data at all. It only changes how you see the results after you run that `SELECT`. You need to use `UPDATE` if you want it changed forever, or include the `ISNULL` again on your 2nd query.

Comment: `ISNULL()` is not update `NULL` values. It just display as `No Name`..

Comment: Your question aside, I can tell you you're probably making more trouble for yourself than if you left the names null (or even an empty string would be better, if you're not a fan of nulls). I've run across many a data set that contains things like `-32768` for nulls or `NaN` when a null indicates that universally.

Comment: @Squirrel Beautiful! That worked. Im super new to SQL and didn't realise that even though im entering both queries at once, they're considered separate.

Comment: @Xedni Unfortunately it's one of the questions in my assessment, but i've figured it out!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also, listen to @Xedni, store null values in the table, not anything else.

Comment: Use `COALESCE()` instead of that old `ISNULL()`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realised thanks to Squirrel and other commenters that the way I was typing the query was making it two separate queries.

The correct way I found was to combine them into one:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), ISNULL(Name, 'No Name')
FROM dbo.People
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 3):

use case when

```
select sum(case when name='No Name' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt,name from
(
 SELECT coalesce(Name, 'No Name' ) as name
 FROM dbo.People
) t group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to get the NULL occurences?

No need to overcomplicate things then, just remember that you cannot compare against a lack of value/data but you can check for it.

```
SELECT Count(ID) 
FROM dbo.People 
WHERE Name IS NULL
```